# USB Mouse doesn't work with Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, usb, mouse

I installes Ubuntu 12.10, but I got a problem with my mouse. It's a USB Mouse, the Drakonia Sharkoon. It doesn't work, I can't move it and also can't click something. But there are some keys on my mouse,when pressing one of the keys it should press "1", those keys work. My touchpad is also working. Could someone please help me? Kind regards